# Show that if GL $\vdash$ X then for all interpretations $\xi_i$ of GL in PA, PA $\vdash \xi_i(X)$

Tags: logic, provability

I'm trying to show the above. We define interpretations as follows:

For any provability predicate $Pr(v_1)$, and $i$ any mapping from $\{ \bot, p_1, ..., p_n, ...\}$ (where $p_i$ are the sentence letters of GL) to sentences in the language of PA, we define an interpretation $\xi_i$ of GL in PA (Peano Aritmetic) wrt $i$ and $Pr(v_1)$ as:

$\xi_i (\bot) = i(\bot)$

$\xi_i (p_n) = i(p_n)$

$\xi_i ((X \supset Y)) = \xi_i (X)\supset \xi_i (Y)$

$\xi_i (\Box X) = Pr(\ulcorner \overline{\xi_i(X)}\urcorner)$

I think I'm struggling with understanding how PA and GL are related. I'm assuming for the proof I need to do a deduction in PA, but how do I 'convert' what we're given from GL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GL is basically PA but with all the details "abstracted away", apart from propositional logic and the provability predicate. You can think of the sentence letters $p_i$ as standing for formulas in PA, but it doesn't really matter which ones. What this "Soundness" result tells us is that a proof in GL provides a template for proofs in PA, where we get the proof in PA by choosing a proof predicate to replace $\square$ and PA sentences to replace the $p_i$s.

Here's how the proof works: since we're given a proof in $\mathrm{GL}$, we'll proceed by induction on the length of that proof. What this means in practice is that we'll have to show that the axioms and rules of inference for $\mathrm{GL}$ still hold in PA, after interpreting them using $\xi_i$.

I'll give an example here. One of the axioms for GL is distribution: for any GL sentences $X$ and $Y$: 
$$\mathrm{GL} \vdash ( \square (X \supset Y) \supset (\square X \supset \square Y))$$ 
What we need to prove is:
$$\mathrm{PA} \vdash \xi_i \big(\square (X \supset Y) \supset (\square X \supset \square Y)\big)$$
Using the rules for interpretations, this is the same as:
$$\mathrm{PA} \vdash \big( Pr (\overline{ \ulcorner \xi_i(X) \supset \xi_i(Y) \urcorner}) \supset ( Pr (\overline{\ulcorner \xi_i(X) \urcorner} )\supset Pr(\overline{\ulcorner \xi_i(Y) \urcorner}) \big) $$
This is just an instance of $P_2$ in the definition of a proof predicate, so this holds.

All that remains is to do a similar proof for the remaining two axioms and the two rules of inference.